# How to refresh the custom list view in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using the custom list view in this I am using sqlite data base to store the data. Now I want to deleting the data from custom list view the data is deleting no problem in that but after deleting I want to refresh the list I have used simplaAdapter to bind the list.

```
sa=new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), liHm, R.layout.customlist, val, id);
listview.setAdapter(sa);
```

and to refresh the data  I am using this code but its not working

```
sa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: try to initialize adapter again after successful deletion and set again to listview. may be that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. i put the array adapter inside one method after deleting the event i called that method.
2. so automatically listview has been changed